# missing args do not show defined error message

Tags: python

This is my first post, so please excuse any missing info or stupid questions.So what I am trying to do is run a command line python script (I'm in a Windows machine), pass it 2 arguments, check if the arguments were passed, if not, display an error message specific to that argument. I am getting a missing argument error, but it isnt displaying the message I would like (defined in the function). I'm not sure if I didn't create the function properly, or if I am missing something. I also want to check if the arguments passed are correct strings, not int, but it seems that the arguments are defaulting to strings, so checking if they are int is not working either.

Can someone give me a hint or point me in the right direction? I've been searching online but havent found anything that has answered this question. I am brand new to python, so still learning how to read documentation properly (seems like there are too few examples for me to understand the docs). Here is the code I am using:

```
    import argparse

    #parser to create and grab args from CLI

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-i", help="File path of original folder")
    parser.add_argument("-o", help="File path of output folder")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    #check if args have been passed and display error if missing

    def check_args(input_path,output_path):

        if input_path == None:
            print("Please input a valid folder path for original folder destination")
        elif output_path == None:
            print("Please input a valid folder path for output folder destination")
        else:
            return args

    #grab first and sec argument

    input_path = args.i
    output_path = args.o

    check_args(input_path, output_path)
```

Output:

```
    Program>python JPGtoPNG_conv.py -i 3 -o
    usage: JPGtoPNG_conv.py [-h] [-i I] [-o O]
    JPGtoPNG_conv.py: error: argument -o: expected one argument
```

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: ` check_args` is not called since argparse stop the flow and throw an exception. Isnt it OK with you?

Comment: You don't *need* this check. `parse_args` itself prevents you from setting `args.o` to the value you think you need to check for.

Comment: The check you really want to make inside `check_args` is something like `os.path.exists(output_path)`.

Comment: AWESOME!!! Thanks so much everyone for your comments. With everyone's input, I figured out how to solve it, and learned a lot. I really appreciate all the help.

Answer (score -1):

The code below should do the job for you

```
import argparse
import sys


class MyParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def error(self, message):
        sys.stderr.write('error: %s\n' % message)
        self.print_help()
        sys.exit(2)


parser = MyParser()
parser.add_argument("-i", help="File path of original folder", required=True)
parser.add_argument("-o", help="File path of output folder", required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

# grab first and sec argument

input_path = args.i
output_path = args.o
```

Comment: The OP *is* using the option; they are just omitting the required argument.